# How to install BibleMemorizer in Ubuntu 14.04 and later?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

The [BibleMemorizer package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/biblememorizer) is not anymore in the usual archive/repository of Ubuntu 14.04 (and later). Is there a possibility to still **install** it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Jeremy](http://sourceforge.net/u/jerickson314/profile/), one of the project manager: **Yes**!
It's actually possible to get BibleMemorizer running by **compiling** it yourself. It is designed it to **compile with both Qt3 and Qt4**, as long as you have the **Qt3 support library**.
**Download** the tar.gz-package from the [Sourceforge project page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblememorizer/).
**Extract** it.
Open a **terminal** (Command line):

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev libqt4-qt3support g++  
cd path-to-the-extracted-folder (Go to the biblememorizer-0.6.4 directory from the source code download)  
./configure  
make  
sudo make install
```

The app will then show up in the usual places. If it gives plugin errors, you may need to change the plugin directory in Settings to /usr/lib/biblememorizer/plugins and pick the "English language book names" plugin. (The Sword plugin seems to cause a crash on my machine.)